# Is there a cheatsheet for linux commands to save your system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I've recently lost my window options, had to somehow manipulate my way to Xchat and ask some people how do I get it back (it was `metacity --replace`, and after I decided to stop the command and run it in background the X was completely useless so I had to do killall -u user). 
And that was after the internet connection stopped working for some reason (might've been the ISP).

The thing is, after using linux a long time, I still get the feeling 
that on dire situations, I don't know the good tricks (stuff like `metacity --replace`).
I feel like a really need like a "rescue" cheatsheet for things like:

- how to save the X no matter what without pressing reset
- how to reset the system to "normal state"
- how to connect to the internet through the command line
- how to monitor what the X is doing
  (using ubuntu linux 10.04 btw)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### X

If it's working: Ctrl-Alt-Backspace.

Ctrl-Alt-F[1-6] go to terminal.

Ctrl-Alt-F7 - go to X

Restart XDM in most distros:

```
/etc/init.d/xdm restart
```

Or find X processes PIDs

```
ps aux|grep "[Xx]"
```

and kill them. Then start new X

```
startx
```

X logs: /var/log/Xorg.0.log

### Internet

Using dhcp:

```
dhclient interface
```

Interface could be eth0.
Without

```
ifconfig ...
```

or

```
ip
```

(see man for more)

Not sure how Ubuntu works, but i think you can restart your network connecting using some kind of /etc/init.d script.
Check [server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/networking.html). Not sure, but I think that works for desktop edition too.

### Other stuff

Useful terminal programs:

- lynx,links - internet browsers
- irssi - IRC client
- mc - file manager
- mcedit - simplest file editor ever
- GNU and system utils - basic like: cat, tail, head, cp, rm, mv - must know!
- top, ps - display Linux tasks
- free - memory usage (but remember to look at buffors table, not mem)
- man :)

[Magic Resq Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

[Wikibooks Freezes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_Guide/Freezes)

Comment: I may add that from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, you can't directly call /etc/init.d. Just call "service" instead. Also, xdm can refer to kdm or gdm, whichever desktop you use. Also, of "useful terminal programs", I would add "pico" as a text editor. Or "vim", if you know how to use it, but it is not installed by default on Ubuntu (though I think it is on most other distros).

Comment: I have two more apps on my mind.

mc - file manager

mcedit - very basic and very simple editor.

Comment: @petersohn: you can still use /etc/init.d/<service> <action>, and not all services have been converted to use Upstart yet anyway.

Comment: ohh, I printed it out before you added the extra commands :)

Comment: @Graeme: But you must use "service" for gdm/kdm (for me it only worked that way). @gogiel: Do not forget find, dd. Anything else?

Comment: There is really a lot commands and cheatsheets, use Google.
http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html
Important one: wget 
More interesting stuff: http://serverfault.com/questions/68883/linux-command-line-best-practices-and-tips

Answer (score 1):

I'm a programmer, so I use [git](http://git-scm.org) daily.

I have found git very useful for monitoring changes (and eventually restoring in emergency cases) changes in config files.

Edit:

On my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS I do:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

or

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: I also use git, however I don't really understand where does git come to place on these commands?

Comment: Well, my answer has two parts: git for undoing things when in trouble; and the commands extending @petersohn's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what your looking for, but I found this .pdf to be a good resource for figuring out ubuntu. (Plus its free...which is always nice.)

http://ubuntu-manual.org/